# Spark Streaming: in-memory aggregation - correct usage

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a Spark 2.2 Structured streaming flow from an on-premise system into a containerized cloud spark cluster where kafka recieves the data, and SSS maintains a number of queries that flush to disk every ten seconds. A query console-sink is not accessible to external sessions outside the streaming context (hence the CSV flush); the monitoring dashboard runs spark sql from another context to get metrics.

Right now I am only aggregating the data that has come in since streaming was last started. Now I need to aggregate data since forever with the incoming streaming data to provide (near) realtime views. This will mean running a bunch of GROUP BY's on billions of records - maintaining several million aggregate rows in-memory.

My question is regarding how Spark streaming queries can scale like this: how efficient is memory usage (I'll probably use 32 worker contaiers) and is this the correct way to manage a (near-) realtime view of incoming data using kafka and SSS?

Comment: My question is quite similar to yours. Please post any advance on this to my question as well.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043791/spark-structured-streaming-feasible-for-lots-of-concurrent-statefull-queries